How to manage multiple exit conditions in PineScript?
I want to exit a certain positions when certain conditions are met. My conditions are following:

TP1 - When price passes a calculated %. This is not a static value, but for simplicity, let's make this 5%.
TP2 - Same as TP1 but when it passes 10%.
SL - When price dips below certain %.
SL to BE - When price passes a certain threshold e.g. 3%.

Now I tried everything I guess. strategy.exit() and strategy.close() and their combinations and I always face a problem, where one thing cancels or ignores another and it's just a hell of a mess to handle.
CASE1: Using strategy.close(), it never triggers TP2; TP1 and SL work fine.
Code for case1:
// TP1 and SL BE
if (tp1_cond and not tp1_taken) //and not tp1_taken)
    strategy.close(tradeId, qty_percent = tp1perc, comment="TP1: "+str.tostring(tradeId)) 
    //strategy.exit("TP1: "+str.tostring(tradeId), from_entry=tradeId, profit = 1,  qty_percent = tp1perc) // one exit order somehow cancels another, despite different IDs
    //strategy.exit("SL BE "+str.tostring(tradeId), from_entry=tradeId, qty_percent = 100-tp1perc, stop=entryPrice) // TODO: Figure out why this is decreasing strategy performance - smth to do with one order canceling another I guess
    array.set(tp1_taken_arr, tp1_index, true)

// TP2
if (tp2_cond and not tp2_taken)
    strategy.close(tradeId, qty_percent = tp2perc, comment="TP2: "+str.tostring(tradeId)) 
    //strategy.exit("TP2: "+str.tostring(tradeId), from_entry=tradeId, profit = 1,  qty_percent = tp2perc)
    array.set(tp2_taken_arr, tp2_index, true)
    
// Stop-loss condition
if (stopLossCond)
    strategy.close(tradeId, comment="SL: "+str.tostring(tradeId), immediately = true)
    //strategy.exit("SL", from_entry = tradeId, stop = entryPrice)

CASE2: If I switch to using strategy.exit(), only POP - condition #4 and SL - condition #3 work.
Code for case2:
// TP1 and SL BE
if (tp1_cond and not tp1_taken) //and not tp1_taken)
    //strategy.close(tradeId, qty_percent = tp1perc, comment="TP1: "+str.tostring(tradeId)) 
    strategy.exit("TP1: "+str.tostring(tradeId), from_entry=tradeId, profit = 1,  qty_percent = tp1perc) // one exit order somehow cancels another, despite different IDs
    //strategy.exit("SL BE "+str.tostring(tradeId), from_entry=tradeId, qty_percent = 100-tp1perc, stop=entryPrice) // TODO: Figure out why this is decreasing strategy performance - smth to do with one order canceling another I guess
    array.set(tp1_taken_arr, tp1_index, true)

// TP2
if (tp2_cond and not tp2_taken)
    //strategy.close(tradeId, qty_percent = tp2perc, comment="TP2: "+str.tostring(tradeId)) 
    strategy.exit("TP2: "+str.tostring(tradeId), from_entry=tradeId, profit = 1,  qty_percent = tp2perc)
    array.set(tp2_taken_arr, tp2_index, true)
    
// Stop-loss condition
if (stopLossCond)
    //strategy.close(tradeId, comment="SL: "+str.tostring(tradeId), immediately = true)
    strategy.exit("SL", from_entry = tradeId, stop = entryPrice)
    
// Check if price has popped by the break-even threshold and move stop loss to break-even - increased peformance of the strategy and decreased the drawdown - if set specifically at 3%, needs some experimenting
if (currentProfit >= slBeThreshold)
    strategy.exit("POP - Move to BE: "+str.tostring(tradeId), from_entry=tradeId, stop=entryPrice)
enter code here

CASE3: If I comment out the condition #4 and use strategy.exit() all 3 things work TP1, TP2 and SL work fine.
Code for case3 (same as case 2, with added condition for #4):
// TP1 and SL BE
    if (tp1_cond and not tp1_taken) //and not tp1_taken)
        //strategy.close(tradeId, qty_percent = tp1perc, comment="TP1: "+str.tostring(tradeId)) 
        strategy.exit("TP1: "+str.tostring(tradeId), from_entry=tradeId, profit = 1,  qty_percent = tp1perc) // one exit order somehow cancels another, despite different IDs
        //strategy.exit("SL BE "+str.tostring(tradeId), from_entry=tradeId, qty_percent = 100-tp1perc, stop=entryPrice) // TODO: Figure out why this is decreasing strategy performance - smth to do with one order canceling another I guess
        array.set(tp1_taken_arr, tp1_index, true)

// TP2
if (tp2_cond and not tp2_taken)
    //strategy.close(tradeId, qty_percent = tp2perc, comment="TP2: "+str.tostring(tradeId)) 
    strategy.exit("TP2: "+str.tostring(tradeId), from_entry=tradeId, profit = 1,  qty_percent = tp2perc)
    array.set(tp2_taken_arr, tp2_index, true)
    
// Stop-loss condition
if (stopLossCond)
    //strategy.close(tradeId, comment="SL: "+str.tostring(tradeId), immediately = true)
    strategy.exit("SL", from_entry = tradeId, stop = entryPrice)

EDIT1:
The best combination, that somewhat works so far and executes TP1, TP2 and SL properly is this. However, it doesn't take care of the POP - #4 condition nor can I expand and add more conditions...
// TP1 and SL BE
if (tp1_cond and not tp1_taken) //and not tp1_taken)
    strategy.close(tradeId, qty = tradeQty * tp1perc/100, comment="TP1: "+str.tostring(tradeId)) 
    //strategy.exit("TP1: "+str.tostring(tradeId), from_entry=tradeId, profit = 1,  qty = tradeQty * tp1perc) // one exit order somehow cancels another, despite different IDs
    //strategy.exit("SL BE "+str.tostring(tradeId), from_entry=tradeId, qty_percent = 100-tp1perc, stop=entryPrice) // TODO: Figure out why this is decreasing strategy performance - smth to do with one order canceling another I guess
    array.set(tp1_taken_arr, tp1_index, true)

// TP2
if (tp2_cond and not tp2_taken)
    //strategy.close(tradeId, qty = tradeQty * tp1perc/100, comment="TP2: "+str.tostring(tradeId)) 
    strategy.exit("TP2: "+str.tostring(tradeId), from_entry=tradeId, profit = 1,   qty = tradeQty * tp2perc/100)
    array.set(tp2_taken_arr, tp2_index, true)
    
// Stop-loss condition
if (stopLossCond)
    //strategy.close(tradeId, comment="SL: "+str.tostring(tradeId), immediately = true)
    strategy.exit("SL: "+str.tostring(tradeId), from_entry = tradeId, stop = entryPrice)


I think I somehow figured it out, but more and smarter answers are still welcome. Important is the order of those exits and closes... TP2 will always happen at last, so over there, I am using strategy.close() so I don't have to think about the quantities or conflict with the POP condition.
 // TP1 and SL BE
if (tp1_cond and not tp1_taken) //and not tp1_taken)
    //strategy.close(tradeId, qty = tradeQty * tp1perc/100, comment="TP1: "+str.tostring(tradeId)) 
    strategy.exit("TP1: "+str.tostring(tradeId), from_entry=tradeId, profit = 1,  qty = tradeQty * tp1perc/100) // one exit order somehow cancels another, despite different IDs
    //strategy.exit("SL BE "+str.tostring(tradeId), from_entry=tradeId, qty_percent = 100-tp1perc, stop=entryPrice) // TODO: Figure out why this is decreasing strategy performance - smth to do with one order canceling another I guess
    array.set(tp1_taken_arr, tp1_index, true)

// TP2
if (tp2_cond and not tp2_taken)
    strategy.close(tradeId, comment="TP2: "+str.tostring(tradeId)) 
    //strategy.exit("TP2: "+str.tostring(tradeId), from_entry=tradeId, profit = 1,   qty = tradeQty * tp2perc/100)
    array.set(tp2_taken_arr, tp2_index, true)
    
// Stop-loss condition
if (stopLossCond)
    //strategy.close(tradeId, comment="SL: "+str.tostring(tradeId), immediately = true)
    strategy.exit("SL: "+str.tostring(tradeId), from_entry = tradeId, stop = entryPrice)
    
//Check if price has popped by the break-even threshold and move stop loss to break-even - increased peformance of the strategy and decreased the drawdown - if set specifically at 3%, needs some experimenting
if (currentProfit >= slBeThreshold )
    if (tp1_taken)
        strategy.exit("SL BE: "+str.tostring(tradeId), from_entry=tradeId, stop=entryPrice, qty = tradeQty - tradeQty * tp1perc/100)
    else
        strategy.exit("SL BE: "+str.tostring(tradeId), from_entry=tradeId, stop=entryPrice)

What this does however, is that it fills a long position, takes partial profit when TP1 condition is met, then moves SL BE for just a portion of the order and the rest of the order runs till either SL or TP2 is hit. Somehow I can't make the rest to run till either SL BE or TP2 is hit... which is basically my ultimate goal + I want to move SL BE before TP1.
EDIT1:
Found a way around by extensive conditioning and canceling exit orders  before triggering TPs or creating new exit orders. strategy.cancel("SL BE: "+str.tostring(tradeId))
